# Iterative process that leads to Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I want $x$ to be Poisson distributed.

I will call occupation probability $p(x=n) =: p(n)$ and the transition probability $p(x=n \rightarrow x=n+1) =: p(n \rightarrow n+1)$

The value of $x$ is changed in a stochastic iterative process. Changes of $\pm1$ are possible. I need the transition probabilities $p(n \rightarrow n+1)$ and $p(n \rightarrow n-1)$ that lead to a poisson distributed $x$ after $m \to \infty$ iterations.

The [detailed balance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance) condition 
$$p(n) \cdot  p(n \rightarrow n+1) = p(n+1) \cdot p(n +1  \rightarrow n)$$
leads to
$$p(n+1)=  p(n) \frac{ p(n \rightarrow n+1)}{ p(n +1  \rightarrow n)}$$

The occupation probability of a Poisson-distributed variable can be written as
$$ p(n+1)=p(n) \frac{\lambda}{n+1}$$

Therefore we get 
$$\frac{ p(n \rightarrow n+1)}{ p(n +1  \rightarrow n)}=  \frac{\lambda}{n+1}$$

I thought it'd be good in order to obtain the best efficiency to force a change in every iteration by setting

$$ p(n \rightarrow n+1) + p(n \rightarrow n-1) = 1 $$

So i get the recursion rules:

$$ p(n \rightarrow n+1) = 1- p(n \rightarrow n-1) $$
$$ p(n \rightarrow n-1) = \frac{n}{\lambda} p(n-1 \rightarrow n)$$

This defines the series but for a constant $p(0 \rightarrow 1) =: p_0$

However, i clearly messed something up, because if i calculate the explicit values for the transition probability i obtain something like e.g.
$$ p(1 \rightarrow 2) =1- \frac {p_0 }{ \lambda}  $$
which is obviously not a probability since $\lambda$ is an arbitrary parameter and if $\lambda \lt p_0$ this leads to negative results...

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2005/lecture-notes/18_05_lec8.pdf

Comment: @dato I don't get what you intended to tell me with your comment. I know how a Poisson distribution looks like. Do you think my recursive form of the Poisson distribution is wrong?

Comment: does anyone have an idea?